# Inserting multiple records at once into SQL Server using Pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `.CSV` file that has data of the form:

```
2006111024_006919J.20J.919J-25.HLPP.FMGN519.XSVhV7u5SHK3H4gsep.log,2006111024,K0069192,MGN519,DN2BS460SEB0
```

This his how it appears in a text file. In Excel the commas are columns.

The `.csv` file can have 100s of these rows. To make things easier both coding and reading the code, I am using pandas mixed with SQL Alchemy. I am new to Python and all these modules

my initial method gets all the info but does one insert at a time for each row of a csv file. My mentor says this is not the best way and that I should use a "bulk" insert/read all rows of the csv then insert them all at once. My method so far uses pandas df.to_sql. I hear this method has a "multi" mode for insert. The problem is, I have no idea how to use it with my limited knowledge and how it would work with the method I have so far:

```
def odfsfromcsv_to_db(csvfilename_list, db_instance):
    odfsdict = db_instance['odfs_tester_history']

    for csv in csvfilename_list:  # is there a faster way to compare the list of files in archive and history?
        if csv not in archivefiles_set:
            odfscsv_df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, names=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WF_SCRIBE'])
            #print(odfscsv_df['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'])
            for index, row in odfscsv_df.iterrows():
                table_row = {
                    "ODFS_LOG_FILENAME": row['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME'],
                    "ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME": row['ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME'],
                    "LOT": row['LOT'],
                    "TESTER": row['TESTER'],
                    "WF_SCRIBE": row['WF_SCRIBE'],
                    "CSV_FILENAME": csv.name
                }
               
                print(table_row)
                df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([table_row])
                result = df1.to_sql('odfs_tester_history', con=odfsdict['engine'], if_exists='append', index=False)
                
        else:
            print(csv.name + " is in archive folder already")
```

How do I modify this and be able to insert multiple records at once. I felt limited to creating a new dictionary for each row of the table and then inserting that dictionary into the table for each row. Is there a way to collate the rows into one big structure and push them all at once into my db using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the pd.read you would just need to use the following code:

```
odfscsv_df.to_sql('DATA', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

Where DATA is your table, conn is your connection, etc. the two links below should help you with any specifics to your code, and I have attached a snippet of some old code that might help to make it clearer, however, the two links below are the better resource.

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html?highlight=sql#io-sql

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

conn = None;

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # This allows the database to run in RAM, with no requirement to create a file.
    #conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')  # You can create a new database by changing the name within the quotes.
except Error as e:
    print(e)

c = conn.cursor() # The database will be saved in the location where your 'py' file is saved IF you did not choose the :memory: option
# Create table - DATA from input.csv - this must match the values and headers of the incoming CSV file.
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA
             ([generated_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
              [What] text, 
              [Ever] text, 
              [Headers] text, 
              [And] text, 
              [Data] text,
              [You] text, 
              [Have] text)''')  

conn.commit()
# When reading the csv:
# - Place 'r' before the path string to read any special characters, such as '\'
# - Don't forget to put the file name at the end of the path + '.csv'
# - Before running the code, make sure that the column names in the CSV files match with the column names in the tables created and in the query below
# - If needed make sure that all the columns are in a TEXT format

read_data = pd.read_csv (r'input.csv', engine='python')
read_data.to_sql('DATA', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False) # Insert the values from the csv file into the table 'DATA'

# DO STUFF with your data

c.execute('''
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DATA
    ''')
conn.close()
```

Comment: But I need to pull multiple records from the table. By that I mean, I need to insert multiple records into the sql at once. Not just one table. Hell I don't even know how to pull out all of the rows of that csv and then put them all into sql without doing it row by row @user13802268

Comment: I also don't see a parameter for data. Are you saying I'd insert the whole thing inside data? What does 'DATA' mean here for you? @user13802268

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer by just feeding the dataframe straight to sql. It is a slight modification of @user13802268's answer:

```
odfscsv_df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, names=['ODFS_LOG_FILENAME', 'ODFS_FILE_CREATE_DATETIME', 'LOT', 'TESTER', 'WAFER_SCRIBE'])
result = odfscsv_df.to_sql('odfs_tester_history', con=odfsdict['engine'], if_exists='append', index=False)
```